# Writing Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) with .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, vsix, .net-5

I am working on a VS 2019 Extension that is currently using .NET Framework (4.8). I want to upgrade it to .NET 5.0 but the VSIX project does not support it or any .NET Core version. I want to avoid .NET Standard if at all possible. I can find no info on the next Visual Studio version (2021?) and if .NET 5.0 VSIX projects will be supported or not. I would think Microsoft would be working on this but on the other hand VS is still a 32 bit app. :-)
Sorry if this is not the right venue but this is my first question here.

Comment: _"I want to upgrade it...but the VSIX project does not support it or any .NET Core version. I want to avoid .NET Standard if at all possible."_ - you do realise that [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is nothing but a `baseline` of _all_ .NET implementions (including .NET Core) that meet the spec at a certain point in time.  So if you intended to use _.NET Core 3.0_ well that's just something that is under the _.NET Standard 2.1_ banner.   Going forward it is just .NET 5, a single implemention for everything.  The rest is kinda moot

Comment: Why not just put the majority of your code in a .NET 5 project and reference it from your .NET Framework 4.8 VSIX project?

Comment: Yes, but I want to develop the extension in full .NET 5.0 and not a subset. A VSIX project only supports .NET Framework. Also I think to use .NET Standard the project file needs to be in the SDK format. All of my other sub projects are in SDK format but I don't think I can upgrade the VSIX project file. The VSIX project template has some unique stuff.  I will look into that further as I like the SDK project file format. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, the VSIX project is nothing but the skeleton for code and installer package.  Write the rest in a different assembly using whatever you like so long as it can be referened.   Why are you so keen to put everything in one project?  Best to decouple things

Comment: I have decoupled... there are over 20 other class library projects. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787921/interactive-window-support-for-multiple-runtimes-net-core-in-vsix-template

Comment: I could make the libraries directly referenced by the VSIX project target standard/5.0 but I don't think i can make the VSIX project target standard/4.8, only 4.8. I think I did find a way to convert the VSIX project to SDK format but will need to test further.

Comment: We seem to be talking about the same thing.  VSIX project = 4.8.  Libraries = Standard _x.y_

Comment: @MickyD - I tried putting the libraries in .NET 5 and the VSIX project as .NET Framework 4.8.  Why am I getting **Project '..\GammaFour.DataModelGenerator.Client\GammaFour.DataModelGenerator.Client.csproj' targets 'net5.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'** ?  This looks like exactly what you were suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main extension must be x86 .NET Framework, as it is hosted by the VS process. You could move some your your functions to .NET Standard 2.0, or to a .NET Core 5.0 console app.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I can take advantage of all of the 5.0 features in a Standard 2.0 library however and I cant run these libraries out of process. I think I will just have to wait for Microsoft to update VS to .NET 5.0 internally. (Hopefully VS 2021)

Comment: Don't hold your breath

Comment: I wont... Its 2021 and VS is still a 32 bit app!

Comment: @Jim I know it doesn't help, but it's still 2021 and VS is now 64 bit!

Comment: Finally!!!!  VS 2022 is 64 bit but still runs on .NET Framework. (I understand that they don't want to introduce 2 major changes in one rev) I will have to wait at least to the next rev (2024?) for .NET 5 or 6 or whatever Core version there is by then. Still not holding breath.